# Can we access Ember.TEMPLATES in controller?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

Is it possible to use Ember.TEMPLATES to check the existence of a template within a controller or component?  I am using v1.12.1

We are currently transitioning to a route that is rendering a template that may not exist.  Prior to the transition, we need an existence check of the template to determine whether we should transition.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what you have currently/ what you prefer (hope to have instead) ?

Comment: Toran - I added some detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you `this.container.has('template:someName')`

As a `someName` you can put i.e. `inbox.index` or `inbox/index`

Comment: This did exactly what we wanted. Thanks for feedback.